# Is there a Pythonic paradigm for accessing multidimensional lists using special class methods?

Tags: python, list

Given a custom `dataclass` representing a 2D list, is there a Pythonic or particularly elegant way of providing different modification methods via the special class methods i.e. `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`.

For example, say the first dimension were streets, and the second houses. You want to be able to grab an entire street, as well as individual houses. Similarly, you want to create entire streets, as well as individual houses on an existing street.

I know you could use a mixture of default arguments, or tuples with type/length checking. Or you could also play it safe and have discrete access functions.

However, this also seems like a problem that would have a classic solution. Thank you!

An example using type checking:

```
class multiDimList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, tuple):
            x, y = index
            return self._data[x][y]
        else:
            return self._data[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if isinstance(index, tuple):
            x, y = index
            self._data[x][y] = value
        else:
            self._data[index] = value

myMDL = multiDimList()
print(myMDL[0])
print(myMDL[0, 0])
myMDL[0] = [9, 10, 11]
print(myMDL[0])
myMDL[0, 0] = 12
print(myMDL[0])
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
0
[9, 10, 11]
[12, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Lists don't have multiple dimensions. In any case, it would be really helpful if you gave concrete examples of what you are talking about

Comment: Is a list of lists not a multidimensional list? This seems like semantic hair-splitting.

Comment: No, it isn't. List objects are not aware of the fact that they might happen to contain lists, the API does not know or care about dimensions. Compare this to `numpy.ndarray` objects, which **are** dimensionally aware... For example, they support multidimensional indexing, list objects do not

Comment: However, as stated in the question I am creating a custom dataclass which I want to allow for read/write at both the first and second dimension.

Comment: Again, can you add a small, concrete example of what you want to accomplish, it always helps a question gain more traction. Especially, it is helpful at clarifying the approaches you already said you don't want to do

Comment: Very reasonable. Added an example using the a type checking method.

Comment: `numpy.lib.index_tricks.py` defines some classes that have custom `get/set item` methods.  As you do, they check if the argument is a tuple, and parse its content accordingly.  I believe allowing indexing with tuples was a gift from python developers to `numpy` ones, so almost all examples like this will be found in `numpy` (or derivative packages).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [NumPy](https://numpy.org/). If you create `myMDL` as a [NumPy array](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array), it works exactly as you want.

```
import numpy as np

myMDL = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])

print(myMDL[0])
print(myMDL[0, 0])
myMDL[0] = [9, 10, 11]
print(myMDL[0])
myMDL[0, 0] = 12
print(myMDL[0])
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2]
0
[ 9 10 11]
[12 10 11]
```

Note that it's shown as an array - no commas, leading space before 9.

NumPy supports many other things too, like access on other dimensions. For example to access the second column:

```
>>> print(myMDL[:,1])
[10  4  7]
```

Comment: P.s. I only know the basics of NumPy myself, but I'll do my best to answer any other questions if needed

Comment: Interesting. This definitely is a possible solution, however I'm wondering if it's overkill to include the entire numpy dependency just for a single datatype when I can implement e.g. chepner's solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a start, but it's asymmetric; you can get/set a *row* or an individual element, but not a *column*. The fully symmetric case isn't much harder to implement, since it requires more cooperation from the user.

```
class MultiDimList:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x, y = index
        if isinstance(x, int):
            return self._data[x][y]
        elif isinstance(x, slice):
            return [row[y] for row in self._data[x]]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        x, y = index
        if isinstance(x, int):
            self._data[x][y] = value
        elif isinstance(x, slice):
            for r, v in zip(self._data[x], value):
                r[y] = v

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(''.join(map(str, r)) for r in self._data)


d = MultiDimList()
```

This example doesn't allow the shortcut of having a single integer representing a row; you have to specify both axes.

```
>>> d[0, :]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> d[:, 0]
[0, 3, 6]
>>> d[0, :] = "abc"
>>> d[:, 0] = "xyz"
>>> d[1,1] = "*"
>>> print(d)
xbc
y*5
z78
```

---

If you want to allow a single integer to imply a specific row, you can augment `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` as follows.

```
def _parse_index(self, index):
    try:
        x, y = index
    except ValueError:
        x = index
        y = slice()
    return x, y

def __getitem__(self, index):
    x, y = self._parse_index(index)
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return self._data[x][y]
    elif isinstance(x, slice):
        return [row[y] for row in self._data[x]]

def __setitem__(self, index, value):
    x, y = self._parse_index(index)
    if isinstance(x, int):
        self._data[x][y] = value
    elif isinstance(x, slice):
        for r, v in zip(self._data[x], value):
            r[y] = v
```

Comment: Thank you for the very insightful response! In my specific use-case, I will never need per-column granularity, but the symmetric nature of your solution is definitely something I'm going to research.